# Consultancy: is it inappropriate to put a client's name on linkedin/CV?

Tags: resume, linkedin

I am working as consultant and, up until now, I was involved in projects with several client companies.
So, on linkedin and my CV, I just put something like:

```
-client company 1 - external consultant (via <mycompany>)
--experience1 
--experience2
-client company 2 -external consultant (via <mycompany>)
-- ...
```

I find it one of consultants' advantages: you are actually seeing a lot of different realities in little time and if your consultancy company is good those client companies are actually good names to put on your CV.

Anyway some consultants just put (at least on Linkedin, dunno about their CV) something like:

```
-major UK bank - external consultant (via <company>)
--experience1
--experience2
-major telecom operator - external consultant (via <company>) 
 -- ...
```

In other words they don't actually put the client company's name but just a description.

Why they do that? Maybe I'm the one who's violating some code? Is it inapproriate to put who your clients are?

Comment: You may want to check your company's agreements (or your HR) as there may be confidentiality issues here. I worked as a consultant for a project where we were not allowed to divulge the client's name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It comes down to personal choice and what's appropriate - you'd generally know if it's very confidential or sensitive.

For what it's worth, I'm in the same boat and I agree with your assessment completely - being able to put these organisations on your CV is a major advantage and I have exactly the same layout for those reasons.

Additionally, where it isn't worth separating out (For example, if you're just doing the same thing for lots of clients) I've got a bullet point for example:

- Providing technical consultancy for financial institutions including Bank 1, Bank 2 and Bank 3.

Comment: Agreed, if it's inappropriate you would generally know or have already been told so. Consulting companies with clients where this might be a problem will usually tell you as this is really standard.

Comment: Putting it another way: If you really think the customer might object, ask them if they mind being mentioned as a past client. But most resumes lust past employers and that's rarely a concern, so unless you were working for (or against) a secretive government agency it's probably fine.